# Is there anyway to run my script on the cloud with regular interval?

Tags: python, web, web-crawler

I have writtern some python script to capture the real-time air quality information and weather condition around the world. The data on the source website is updated once in 1 hour.

So, I need to re-run my script by 1 hour and update my saving datafiles. I only have a laptop which is impossible to run continuous about 1 year with not shutting down just for this job.

In this way, I want to ask is there any website that I can upload and run my scripts and it will save the result on the cloud.

#### Add

My script is pretty easy with the support of Python BeautifulSoup.

My target website is offering API key and I have one.

With my test, the script can run in OS.X system and CentOS system.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide more details. On what platform did you planned to run your script?

Answer (score 1):

I think [scrapinghub](https://scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud) meets your requirements perfectly, thought there is a data retention limit, at least in the free and the basic plans.